# Apply styles regardless if the element has been added to the DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

**Problem:** Applying `$(".price").hide();` works to elements already rendered, however, when I load a new template via javascript, the price class will be visible.

**Question:** Is there a way to apply a style to all future instances of a class upon insertion into the DOM.

Example:

```
$(".price").hide();
$('body').append('<div class="price">19.00</div>'); // this should be hidden.
```

Comment: Do you mean *regardless* if the element has been added with jquery, or *if and only if* the element has been added with jquery. If the answer is regardless, why don't you just make the price class have display:none?

Comment: I have a price visibility toggle switch, and when this app is using jQuery.tmpl() to load new templates unfortunately. So depending on the switch, I set visibility for all future classes added to the DOM.

Comment: Then I submit that you're doing it the hard way. Seem my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it this way, make your toggle switch modify a *container* element to add or remove a class.

Then, have a CSS rule that looks like this:

```
.hidePrice .price{
    display:none;
}​
```

When you toggle your button, just toggle the hidePrice class on your container element.

See: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bXChZ/

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

```
$('.price').livequery(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The advantage is that this will cover existing, as well as any new elements you add to the DOM.

**EDIT**: As others have pointed out livequery was written for jQuery 1.3-1.4. So I'm not sure how applicable it would be to your case. <s>Let me see if there is anything equivalent for 1.7.2.</s> Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770359/jquery-livequery-plug-equivalent-in-jquery-1-7) for more information about mimicking livequery's functionality in jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: Are you sure that this will work with jQuery 1.7.2? It was written for 1.3 - 1.4.

Comment: @Blender Well, crap. I've used this before, but I didn't take care to note what version of jQuery I was using. Let me check if it works in 1.7.2

Comment: @VivinPaliath: was gonna down-vote this. last update 2 years back. see the git. no offense. :)

Comment: @naveen None taken, naveen :). My mistake for not checking the version. Seems odd that such a functionality wouldn't exist in 1.7.2.

Comment: I am currently using 1.6.2 on this project. I will see if its compatible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use a helper class:

CSS

```
.helper{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".price").addClass('helper'); //for dyanmic addition to certain classes
$('body').append('<div class="price helper">19.00</div>');  //for adding afterward
```

Comment: The only problem is that the templates are already defined and it would require more work to apply this class after render. But cool idea.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**With jQuery:**

```
$('<style id="priceVisibility">div.results .price {display: none; }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

**Without jQuery:**

```
// Appending style element to the head with a overriding style.
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.id = 'priceVisibility';
style.innerHTML = 'div.results .price {display: none; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a class to the <body> tag, and then hide the .price elements with CSS. E.g.

jQuery:

```
$('body').addClass('hide-price');
```

CSS:

```
.price {display: block}
.hide-price .price {display: none}
```